# ListPlot with conditions

Tags: graphics, plotting

I have a data file containing the position of about $10^5$ stars of a spiral galaxy. Here is the plot

[image]

and this is the corresponding code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SetDirectory[" ... "];

data = Import["data_SGC.out", "Table"];
L0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.001]}, Axes -> False, 
              Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
              RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], 
              AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 100, ImageSize -> 550];
```

As we can see, there are two arms starting at about $(x,y) = (-14.6,0)$ and $(x,y) = (14.6,0)$. Now I would like to customize `ListPLot`, so as the arm starting at the left part $(x,y) = (-14.6,0)$, be in green color, while the other one in red. All the other points between the two yellow banana-type areas should be in gray.

Any suggestions?

The complete data file can be found here: [data](http://www.mediafire.com/view/vrvrf4i2irc96y7/data_SGC.out). Obviously, I could not generate simple random data in order to replicate this complicated spiral structure.

Comment: So if it's just about the `ListPlot`, do we need all the `ContourPlot` and `RegionPlot`? I guess `data = Import[..]` and `ListPlot[...]` would be enough.

Comment: @Öskå You are right, `ContourPlot` and `RegionPlot` are not needed, so I removed them. See the revised post.

Comment: At least now one can read the text and see the picture in the same time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have somehow to segment your data. Here you could use the radius + FindClusters:

```
    radius = 14.6;
    data1 = FindClusters[Select[data, Norm[#] > radius &], 2,Method -> "Agglomerate"];
    Show[
      ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}],
     ListPlot[Select[data, Norm[#] < radius &], PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Gray]
    ]
```

This will give you something like this:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! One minor detail. How can I set correctly `PointSize[0.001]` to all three lists (gree, red, gray)?

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I found the solution.
`PlotStyle -> {Directive[Darker[Green], PointSize[0.001]], 
   Directive[Red, PointSize[0.001]]}]`

Comment: @Öskå Yes it was very easy to set the correct `PointSize`.