# ListPlot with conditions Part II

Tags: graphics, plotting

In a previous post [Part I](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56286/listplot-with-conditions) @Julian S proposed an interesting method in order to segment the data. A copy of the data file can be found here: [data](http://www.mediafire.com/view/nqqav47hhev3sq1/spiral.out). I know that I should provide a minimal working example but the particular structure of the data do not allow me to replicate them with random distributions.

```
data = Import["spiral.out", "Table"];
radius = 15.3;

data1 = FindClusters[Select[data, Norm[#] > radius &], 2, Method -> "Agglomerate"];
L0 = Show[
     ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Darker[Green], PointSize[0.003]], 
     Directive[Red, PointSize[0.003]]}], 
     ListPlot[Select[data, Norm[#] < radius &], PlotRange -> Full, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[0.001], Gray]}]
     ]
```

This works fine if the two spirals do not merge together. Here is an example

[image]

If however the two spiral arms merge the method fails. Here is another example

[image]

So, my question: Is there a way to improve the method in order to work also when the two spiral arms merge together? The spiral that start from + 15.3 should be in green color, while its twin starting from - 15.3 in red.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post what you would consider a "right" coloring of the last picture?